# How to extract specific values from an Array in sql snowflake

Tags: sql, arrays, arraylist, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find values from a specific field which is an array type. I am using snowflake

eg:
I am using ARRAY_CONTAINS and trying to extract multiple values from the field.

```
`select ARRAY_CONTAINS('abc'::variant, FieldName),* from table1`
```

the FieldName is a array field and has multiple values like ['abc',cbs','the',lgj']
I want to extract 'abc and 'the' from the array and create a new field. How can I do this in sql?

Comment: How do you know the ones you want to extract? Is it an array?

Comment: One way is using `ARRAY_SLICE` function.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_slice

Answer (score -1):

GET function can extract a value from an ARRAY
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get